# Chrome Developer Tools - Multiple resources served by same domain

Tags: javascript, resources, grunt-contrib-uglify, chrome-app-developer-tool, google-developer-tools

I'm trying to analyze performance bottlenecks in my web application

I recently ran an audit using chromes Developer Tools

One warning said

```
combine external javascript(11)
There are multiple resources served from same domain. Consider combining them into as few files as possible

11 JavaScript resources served from
```

I did have 11 resources but I combined them into one file using uglify

I looked at the source and found my main.min.js file

Why does the audit still show this message? There is now only one resource